# SQL EXISTS performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, query-performance

I understand that SQL `EXISTS` checks for the existence of rows, however does it evaluate the entire expression? So for example, would something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table WITH (NOLOCK))
BEGIN
    ... 
END
```

Be faster than something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WITH (NOLOCK))
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: How about you execute and look at the Query Execution Plan

Comment: Yep, I just did and they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both those should run exactly the same.  SQL Server takes into account that `EXISTS` is a short-circuited operation and doesn't evaluate the return result, just checks to see if there **IS** a return result!

Answer (score 4):

Exists will stop after the first hit because then the expression evaluates to true, so the top(1)-part is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't.

`SQL Server` uses `TOP` in the plan to evaluate `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

The statements generate identical query plans so there is no difference. The second example is easier to read in my opinion.